# Nginx, Gunicorn, Django: CSS styling not appearing in IE

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Django 2.0 project intended for my work Intranet. I moved the project over to the dedicated Ubuntu 16.04 server. I am new to Gunicorn/Nginx but it was fairly easy to configure and get it running. Everything looks fine in Chrome/Mozilla but in IE there is no CSS styling. If I run the Django development server from the production box, everything looks fine in all browsers. It is only when I run the app through Gunicorn/Nginx that IE sees no CSS styling (Chrome/Mozilla look fine?!). I am not even sure where to start with this one.

Nginix.conf

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
```

Comment: can you post your nginx  conf file ?

Comment: Here is my nginx config file: